# WPF UI Design Issue - Control Visibility

Tags: wpf, user-interface, controls, visibility

I am working on creating a chart user control with extra functionality using the D3 chart control. The following is my UI problem.

I have a tool bar tray at the top, the chart in the middle and a collapsed data grid at the bottom. At the right of the user control is a docksplitter. This docksplitter covers the length of the user control and provides a region where a panel is displayed occasionally.

When I load the user control in a WPF window and set it to stretch, the collapsed data grid at the bottom is not visible even when the data grid is set to visible in code (i.e on click of a button). The chart fills out to the bottom. How do I resolve this issue?

The following is the XAML for the same:

```
<UserControl>
<DockPanel>
    <Grid Name="LnChartEditor" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <osc:DockPanelSplitter x:Name="DocSplitter" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style="{StaticResource VerticalBevelGrip}" Width="7" />        
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="32" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="toolBarTrayTop" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ToolBar x:Name="ToolBarOben" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30">
                <Button Width="30" Height="30">
                </Button>
                <Label x:Name="lblCaption" Width="Auto">                    
                </Label>
                <Popup x:Name="Popup1"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ClearChart}" PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency="true">
                </Popup>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <Grid Name="grdPlotter" Background="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <d3:ChartPlotter Name="LineChart" BorderThickness="10" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <d3:AxisNavigation Placement="Right"/>
                <d3:ChartPlotter.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="D3ContextMenu">
                    </ContextMenu>
                </d3:ChartPlotter.ContextMenu>
            </d3:ChartPlotter>            
        </Grid>
    <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="gridMiniReport" Visibility="Collapsed"          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"                     CanUserSortColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="None">
    </DataGrid>        
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of declaration because the last child fills the remaining space:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid Name="LnChartEditor" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    <osc:DockPanelSplitter x:Name="DocSplitter" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />        
    <ToolBarTray Name="toolBarTrayTop" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="gridMiniReport" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    <Grid Name="grdPlotter" />
</DockPanel>
```